# Firestore - Decrease number if greater than zero

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

Imagine 1 user that can press a button which resets a counter to 0.

In the other side, imagine multiple users (100k, for example) which can increase/decrease the same counter at the same time or whenever they want.

The counter can't never be lower than 0.

What I have thought to do is to run a transaction (read value and then update if necessary), but this seems that, if the counter is updated multiple times before a transaction finishes, it will be repeated again and again, and might ignores some increases if the counter is updated 100k times in a short period and the transaction fails (because of multiple repetitions, maybe I am wrong).

Is the only way to handle this with a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is known as a contention bottleneck, and is a common limit in multi-user systems.

If having 100k concurrent updates to the same data is a realistic scenario in your case, you'll want to look at a different way to solve it.

The first one that comes to mind, and a common solution in general, is to have the users write their increase/decrease to a separate "queue". This can be a collection in Firestore, but the most important thing is that these are append only operations: there is no contention between multiple users writing at the same time.

Then you'd have a Cloud Run instance, or Cloud Functions, process the increase/decrease actions from the users. You can either limit this to at most one concurrent or a few concurrents, leading to either no contention or low contention on updating the final counter.

Comment: And how can I connect the cloud function to this collection in order to update the counter? With a triggered function the chance to get negative counter still exists, right?

Comment: I don't think so, but might not understand the case well enough from the description. That's why I focused on a specific area (write contention) in my answer and explained how you could work around that.

Comment: I think that for now I'm going to play with FieldValue.increment()/distributed counters and see how things scale, since, in my use case, and based on statistics, most of the actions will be increments and not decrements (1000 increments vs less than 10 decrements), so the possibility of getting negative values is really small when the counter is resetted to zero, something that I just realized

Comment: If it were necessary for me in the future, I will try to implement what you tell me, but I still have that little doubt, since if many users add/delete documents to the collection which is listened to by the cloud function, and it happens that the SPECIAL USER resets the counter to zero during the continuous executions of the triggered GCF, and the next actions (of the rest of the triggered function executions) are all decrements, the counter might go to the negative side.